# Links not working inside featherlight popup

Tags: hugo, featherlight.js

I've built a site with Hugo and using [featherlight.js](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) for pop-up lightbox. All working fine when hosted locally. But on the live version I'm having a weird issue where the links inside the pop-up are not working.

A full reproducible example is difficult, but I'll provide the relevant code and perhaps someone can identify what's likely causing the problem or tell me what other info they need.

Relevant code calling `featherlight`:

```
<a class="search-icon"  href="#" data-featherlight="{{ .link | safeURL }}" > <i class="ti-search"></i> </a>
```

Where `.link` is html file compiled from markdown.

If I navigate directly to `.link` the content shows up fine, and the links in the content are fine, e.g.,:

```
<p>See more  <a href="https://www.externalsite.com"> here </a></p>
```

But inside the pop-up lightbox, links in the content appear like this:

```
<p>See more <a href="https://www.externalsite.com"></a>here</p>
```

i.e., 'here' is **outside** the `</a>` tag.

This particular link uses Hugo code:

```
<p> {{.Params.Link_text}}  <a href="{{ .Params.Link | absURL }}" > here </a> </p>
```

But the same thing occurs for the links written with Markdown.

A `featherlight.js` bug or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It works after replacing this `"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"` with `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"`.